# Issue with getting php objects from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

This is the decoded array which i'm getting from url using php curl method,

```
Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => FIRDOUS FAROOQ BHAT [office] => MG Road [age] => 25 [start_date] => 2017-04-27 22:08:11 [salary] => $20000 ) ) )
```

Now the problem is i'm not able to fetch a particular value from it.I used `echo $result->name;` as well as `var_dump['name'];`,i'm getting null value. Can anyone sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your variable name is `$data` where you are storing your this array,

```
echo $data['result'][0]['name'];
echo $data['result'][0]['office'];
```

or (if multiple data)

```
foreach($data['result'] as $res){
   echo $res['name'];
   echo $res['office']; //if office there
   echo $res['age'];
}
```

Comment: And how to display other attributes of array like office ,age etc. by using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You decode you json string into array, you need to use index to access array element like `$result['result'][0]['name'];`. You cannot use `->` to access array element, this operator is used to access element of an object.

Answer (score 0):

If the output you've posted here is stored in `$result`, you would want to access it as such:

```
//Get the first result, and the name from that first result
$result['result'][0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here if result contains more than one element in array. In this case safe way to access your result is. And Here I am considering your response from CURL you will store inside `$result` variable if you will do it like this then below code will helps you.

```
foreach($result['result'] as $singleArray)
{
  echo $singleArray['name'];
}
```

Like this you can access all elements of result array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting an array but you are tried to access the object,
    echo $result->name;

You shouldn't use this instead use this

```
echo $data['result'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: Thank you :)  
Now how can i display all the elements of array in well mannered fashion?